# Any way to create a parent property with pydantic BaseModel?

Tags: python, pydantic

Here's what I'd like to be able to do: get the parent of an object in the hierarchy.

```py
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel

class ModelA(BaseModel):
    field1: str
    field2: str

class ModelB(BaseModel):
    a: ModelA

b = ModelB(**dict(field=dict(field1="asdf", field2="qwer")))

print(b.a.parent)
```

It is always possible to add the property with an `object.__setattr__()` by walking through the hierarchy, but the `.parent` property won't be available to validators.

Any idea?

Comment: What is the expected value of `.parent`?

Comment: parent of `a` is `b`

Comment: As in `b` the variable name? So `b.a.parent = 'b'`? Not `'ModelB'`? (I'm just trying to clarify the use-case, since if you already know `b.a`, as in `a` is a property of `b`, then I don't see a purpose for needing `.parent`.)

Comment: well, it should be the object in variable `b`. On this particular example, yeah, there is not much value. But I'm using pydantic to validate a YAML file, with deeper hierarchies, and some of the checks may need to go between siblings (childrens of b). I'd really like to use the validator infrastructure. I can always write my own and pass the parent (b) in the function calls, but that would be a lot of extra code.